# Getting the source of a click in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var currentImageBox;    
$('.newImage').bind('click', function() {

        currentImageBox = this;
        currentImageBox.unbind('click');
    });
```

Im trying to set currentImageBox to the div that was clicked (a number of divs on the page have the newImage class). But to no avail, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct, the `this` is the element clicked. But to use `unbind`, you need to [wrap the element with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/X47TN/1/) since `this` (and therefore `currentImageBox`) is the DOM element and not a jQuery object.

```
$(currentImageBox).unbind('click');
```

Comment: @user1013512 check the demo, it works. The code unbinds click from the element, like the code does.

Comment: This is better, currentImageBox = $(this); Thanks though.